# Why PHP Symfony sfSessionStorage::initialize sometimes takes a really (really) long time?

Tags: php, performance, symfony, session, io

We have different PHP Apps, both in symfony 1.4 and symfony 2, and all of them, at some point, have requests where sfSessionStorage::initialize takes a very very long time.

I'm talking about several **minutes** to load. Take this newrelic trace for example:

[image]

Here you can see sfSessionStorage::initialize took **185 seconds**. We've been debugging this for several days now, with no success so far. We've looked into GC settings, event tried mounting where the sessions are stored in the filesystem into a RamDisk, with no effect.

What could be the cause of this? Have you ever encontered the same problem? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: some people have a tendency to downvote questions and never explain why. dont let it bother you.

Comment: sucks. Now I have a valid -1 question with less probability of being answered. :(

Comment: Maybe use something like http://blackfire.io to profile the application and see exactly what is happening during that call, it might give you some more insights about what is taking so long

Comment: You haven't done anything crazy like share a session file across multiple requests?

Comment: what do you mean @Cerad? isn't the purpose of the session to persist between requests?

Comment: What I meant was trying to share the same session data between multiple users.  It can be done but leads to file locking problems.  Doubt if you are doing it.  Does your host use windows?

Comment: no im not doing that. no, it's an ubuntu server.

Comment: And you said you tried with a ram disk so there is no chance that your session file is being stored in an nfs mounted disk si it's not a network thing.

Comment: @Cerad that's right. I'm guessing this is some kind of deadlock but I'm not figuring it out. Other requests seem to be queued behind the one that takes a long time, and once that request completes, all the following take almost no time. This repeats several times a day. I coudn't find any other process interfering with this.

Comment: Not sure if related: https://forums.powweb.com/showthread.php?t=77977

Comment: @SomeHelpingDude looks promising, implementing your own sessions manager. I'll give it a look.

Comment: @Cerad I ran into some similar issue while using long polling ajax requests without using `session_write_close`, some time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @SomeHelpingDude pointing to this thread: https://forums.powweb.com/showthread.php?t=77977, there was mentioned the possibility of implementing your own session handler (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

We did that, and implemented a session handler that uses memcached. Now the problem is gone.

I'm assuming the native way of session handling (filesystem) ends up suffering from deadlocks and other performance issues that can only be avoided by not using the filesystem at all.

I'm still puzzled about why a ramdisk didn't fixed this in the first place, so if someone can explain this I will change the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) may shed some light on what's going on.

Assuming you cannot reproduce the problem with cli, I would recommend to limit number of processes to 1 (MaxRequestWorkers for mod_php and max_children for php_fpm), attach strace to the process and check where it hangs.

For example in php_fpm case:

- open `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` and ensure settings

  ```
  pm = static  
  pm.max_children = 1
  ```
- restart php_fpm and nginx
- `grep aux | php` to find out the process id
- `sudo strace -p` followed by the process id
- try to reproduce the problem

If it sticks for minutes with a single system call, you will clearly see the blocker right in the stdout of strace. If there is no single blocker, but rather a long loop of repeated system calls, you will probably need to log it to a file and analyse it later. E.g. `sudo strace -p {pid} | tee /tmp/strace.log`.

If problem is not reproducible with single worker, try to increase number of workers, and capture strace for all processes.

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a try and update with the results.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this will help, but check.

If you handling session manually then you should make Sessions Turning Off, in `frontend/config/factories.yml`

```
all:
  storage:
    class: sfSessionStorage
    param:
      auto_start: false
```

You should see [Deactivating the Unused Features](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/18-Performance) for increasing performance.

**Just another guess :**

Sessions are dependent on files. So check your system is capable of making that many files open required for sessions. Or is there any issue for creating files.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! No, I'm not handling sessions manually. Also, I don't see any OS limitations regarding the amount of opened files. If I were handling sessios manually (which I'm not), your answer points to avoiding creating duplicated sessions?